# JWPlayer 6 Videos don't Display but Audio plays

Tags: jwplayer

I am having a weird issue where my jwplayer videos don't always display their videos, however if autoplay is on the audio will play.

If you refresh the page once it has loaded the video will always load and sometimes they load on the first load of the page. This leads me to believe that it isn't an encoding issue because they play after refresh.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give us a link to your page - we're not psychic. But if you suspect a coding issue, just run your videos through Handbrake with the default options, plus check "web optimized." http://handbrake.fr/

Comment: http://mainejournal.umaine.edu , Some of the videos may load, and some may not, I have no idea how to determine when and why they don't load sometimes. Also, only some article have videos.

Comment: Not willing to go on a hunting expedition. We need a link to a specific page that has JW Player embedded on it, and on which the video consistently fails.

Comment: Please provide a specific example of a video on your site.

Comment: http://mainejournal.umaine.edu/205/ , As I said, after a refresh once, the video will begin to load until you stop for a while, then it may cease to load again.

Comment: Something in your theme seems to be preventing the player from loading. I see it pop up for a second, then disappear again. I noticed that if you copied the player code and pasted it at the bottom of the page, just above the closing </body> tag, the player seems to always show up fine, though.